# How to package jar to a given directory in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

In sbt, if we execute `package`, a jar file will generated at `target/scala-2.12/XXX.jar`. But I want to put the jar file at `myDirectory/XXX.jar`. How can I make this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `target/` part of the default path is defined by the `target` setting key and the `scala-2.12/` part is defined by the `crossTarget` setting (because you may cross-compile for different version of Scala). So a simple solution is to add this to your `build.sbt`:

```
crossTarget := baseDirectory.value / "myDirectory"
```

Now if you call `package` task from sbt, you will get all files the `myDirectory/` directory including the jar, classes and other stuff that normally goes to `target/scala-2.12/`.

If you want to change only the jar's location, you can change the `artifactPath` setting. But you should set it in the right scope and with the jar filename:

```
artifactPath in packageBin in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "myDirectory" / "XXX.jar"

// if you're using sbt 1.1+, you can also write like this:
Compile/packageBin/artifactPath := ...
```

This can easily get more complicated and messy if you have a non-trivial setup. So check the sbt sources to learn how [`artifactPath`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/933668076a2ce76680490273fc7dfadcf18d7dbd/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L1040-L1047) setting is actually defined and read about artifacts in the [sbt documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Artifacts.html).