# Choose directory for package

Tags: scala, sbt

When I execute

```
sbt package
```

It puts my jar into

```
/target/scala-2.11
```

I want it to be in just

```
/target
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to package jar to a given directory in sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357523/how-to-package-jar-to-a-given-directory-in-sbt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see a folder like `scala-2.11` in `target`, this means that [SBT cross-build](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Cross-Build.html) is enabled and artifacts will be produced for each required Scala version.

If you do not need this feature (for example, you build only for scala-2.11 and don't care about others), it can be disabled in `build.sbt` with

```
crossPaths := false
```

All the output previously produced in `scala-2.11` folder will be placed directly into `target`, including the artifact.